# Precision alternative to Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, thread-sleep, scheduledexecutorservice

I need a way to delay a thread for a precise number of milliseconds (a music score playing application). I know that the precision of `Thread.sleep()` is not very good, so I decided to **instead** use `ScheduledExecutorService`. The way I do this is below:

```
... //some code
int duration = 100; //delay for 100ms
CountDownLatch l = new CountDownLatch(1);
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).schedule(l::countDown, duration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
l.await();
... //continue execution
```

Is this a good approach? I am mostly worried about the CountDownLatch, and any delay (if any) it may add.

Thanks.

Comment: Creating a new thread pool every time is not good practice. The scheduled executor doesn't really offer you an improvement in accuracy, unless you can find some documentation that says so? `l.await()` is going to need to be woken up when possible, so it will add delay. Do you have a way to measure the wait times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your solution is not good because of a few issues. You're losing the advantage you gain from using a scheduled executor service by using `await` await is going to put the current thread to sleep, and then the os will need to schedule it again before it starts.

I've made an example using three different techniques. A spin wait, using thread.sleep and using your scheduled executor idea. The spin wait is the most accurate, at 7002ms where the other two solutions are over 8300ms when finished.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class DwellTimes{

    static public void spinWait(long ms){
        long end = System.nanoTime() + ms*1000000;
        long current = System.nanoTime();
        while( current < end){
            current = System.nanoTime();
        }
    }
    
    static public void sleepWait(long ms){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    static ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
     
    static public void scheduleWait(long ms){
        try{
            CountDownLatch l = new CountDownLatch(1);
            ses.schedule(l::countDown, ms, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            l.await();
        } catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
   
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++){
            scheduleWait(7);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println( end + "ms elapsed");
    }
}
```

For a sleep/wait style of flow, the spin wait will be the most accurate because it doesn't release the Thread. It's just going to continue running hot.

The problem with your scheduled executor example is that you're not actually using the scheduling. You want to schedule your tasks.

```
public static void scheduleWork(){
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1000);
    ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(latch::countDown, 7, 7, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    try{
        latch.await();
    } catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This last example is probably the best way to manage consistent timing because you won't continue to accumulate errors. Eg, if your action takes a couple ms, the next action will not be delayed *unless those couple of ms exceed the period*.

Comment: I never considered the spinWait solution you described, because I was worried about CPU usage. However, after giving it a try, it seems that it's not actually an issue (around 15% usage, on my testing phone), so  I will go for it, it looks to be very accurate. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @FlorinM I also added a scheduled executor example that schedules the task. It might be a better technique, but you'll have to reconsider the program flow. The spin wait can drift, and you'll have to keep track of accumulated error. Which the scheduled executor will actually take care of.